# Laravel slash after url redirects to root folder

Tags: php, dynamic, laravel, routes, admin

I'm new to Laravel and it seems a great framework but i have a question when it comes to routing. I want to route all get requests to one controller action named PageController@view but when the prefix is admin i want it to route to Admin\AdminController@view. I have the following code:

```
Route::get('/{slug?}', 'PageController@view');

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@main');
});
```

But when i go to: /admin, Laravel treats it like a slug instead of a prefix. Is there somekind of except function for the first line or do i simply have to switch the above lines to get the right result?

**New problem:**

But now i have a new problem when i go to http://www.mysite.com/laravel/public/admin/, Laravel redirects me to http://www.mysite.com/admin/ instead of calling AdminController@main. When i remove the slash at the end like this: http://www.mysite.com/laravel/public/admin it works fine.

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Don't edit your post here to add new questions to it that is unfair to the user how answered your original question.

Answer (score 13):

If you specify those routes in the opposite order it should work. Do your most specific routes first, and the more generic ones later. Think about it as a "catch this, this, and this, and then fall back to this generic one when none of the above match".

---

Your new problem lies in the (bad, IMO) redirect rule that Laravel 4.1 ships with. The rules very much assume that your Laravel `public` directory sits on the document root of the server. Here's the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301
```

As you can see, that's saying "if the current URL ends in a slash, just redirect it to /{url}", thus getting rid of the slash. This is all well and good, just as long as your installation sits on your server's document root.

You can fix this by specifying a `RewriteBase` (in your case `RewriteBase /laravel/public`) above that rule in your `public/.htaccess` file, but of course, this will now change from environment to environment. This is why i consider the changing of Laravel 4.0's `RedirectIftrailingSlash` functionality to be a `.htaccess` rule to be a bad idea.

Alternatively, you can remove that `RewriteRule` entirely and try not to worry about the fact that your app will now respond on both URLs `/laravel/public/admin` and `/laravel/public/admin/`.

Comment: @user1507868 updated my answer with an answer for the second part of your question.

Comment: Yes, it works. Also, clear cache before visiting the pages.

Comment: Responding to both urls is very bad practice for SEO as its see as duplicate content.

Comment: This is quite probably true, though I'd just like to say that if I was designing a search engine ranking algorithm right now, one thing I'd definitely do is ensure that `/some/url` and `/some/url/` would be classed as the same thing (especially if the content is the same) and just form a convention (no slash IMO) for the canonical version. As such, despite being far from a search engine ranking algorithm expert, I'd be surprised if search engines don't already do this. That said, this 'fact' is touted a lot and I don't think I've ever heard anything to the contrary other than my logic so YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

Check if you have **folder "admin"** in your **public** folder. Laravel automaticaly redirects if there is one.

Answer (score 3):

Since the order matters, try this

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@main');
});

Route::get('/{slug?}', 'PageController@view');
```

**Redirection problem**
Laravel redirects from URL with trailing slash to URL without trailing slash - default behaviour. (If you enter URL without trailing slash -> no redirect needed)
Actual redirection is not the problem. The problem is, Laravel cannot guess right "base" URL and generates wrong redirect URL for you.

Open up `app/config/app.php` and set `url` entry to match root of your project. I guess it is `http://www.mysite.com/laravel/public` in your case.

Comment: I tried that and it works. Thanks! But now i have a second problem. When i go to /admin it works. But when i go to /admin/ it redirects me to http://localhost/admin instead of the public folder of Laravel.

Comment: Edit you question please and post FULL url you are trying to open and FULL url you are redirected to.

Comment: I changed the url to in app/config/app.php but Laravel still redirects me to the root folder.

Comment: i have same problem if find any solution than let me know

Answer (score 1):

The following RewriteRule works for me. I had to remove the / in /$1 from alexrussel's answer above. Including the / redirects me to root folder.

```
#For http://localhost/work/proj1/public/a/ RewriteBase is /work/proj1/public
RewriteBase /repo/qs/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

I am using laravel v4.2, apache v2.4.7, php v5.5.9 on Linux Mint 17 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the directory name, make a rule for it. This works fine for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteRule ^(forum)($|/) - [L]

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?