# Call to controller redirects to root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to create my first route, but it works only if I put an ID in the url. If I don't put any ID (ends with slash), it redirects me to the root of my server. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063520/laravel-slash-after-url-redirects-to-root-folder) that I should erase Laravel's rewrite rule in .htaccess, but it still doesn't work.

My routes :

```
Route::get('musibitmedias/{id}', 'MusibitmediasController@getIndex');
Route::get('musibitmedias', 'MusibitmediasController@getIndex');
```

Part of my controller :

```
# Handles "GET /" request
public function getIndex($id)
     {
        return View::make('musibitmedia')->with('musibitmedias', Musibitmedia::all());
     }
```

Content of my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hash this line in ../public/.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

to

```
# RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since these routes both point to the same method, you can do this with one route by indicating that the `id` parameter may, or may not exist, and setting a default for it in your controller method.

**Route:**

```
Route::get('musibitmedias/{id?}', ['uses' => 'MusibitmediasController@getIndex']);
```

**Controller:**

```
public function getIndex($id = false)
{

   // Is there other code involved?  Where is `$id` used?

   return View::make('musibitmedia', ['musibitmedias' => Musibitmedia::all()]);

}
```

It isn't surprising that you are experiencing some odd behavior as with your current setup, if you hit `/musibitmedias`, it is expecting a parameter to be passed.

Comment: Thanks mr. Griffin, your solution solved one other problem I had :-) but if I call my controller like this : mysite.com/public/controller/, I'm still redirected to mysite.com/controller which doesn't exist. It seems the trailing slash is the problem.