# I have weird behaviour in laravel 5 it redirects me to root when put customers in url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have weird behaviour in laravel 5, it redirects me to root when put customers in url.

like this:

```
localhost:8080/easy_marketing/public/customers
```

it redirects me to

```
http://localhost:8080/customers
```

also,
when use words like those: customers_, customer, _customers they worked fine.

another links like

```
localhost:8080/easy_marketing/public/groups
localhost:8080/easy_marketing/public/keywords
```

they are working fine.

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index'); 
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index'); 
Route::group(['middleware' => 'client'], 
    function() {
        Route::get('customers', 'users\CustomersController@index'); 
        Route::get('customers/import', 'users\CustomersController@import'); 
        Route::post('customers/run-import', 'users\CustomersController@runImport'); 
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not following those URLs with a forward slash, e.g. `localhost:8080/easy_marketing/public/customers/` ? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063520/laravel-slash-after-url-redirects-to-root-folder

Comment: yes without a forward slash, the same i did for groups page, why this page is working correctly. is 'customers' a reserved word in laravel?!

Comment: What does your `routes.php` file look like? Do you have more than one route with the word `customers` in it?

Comment: my route.php    ->    Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'client'], function()
{
    Route::get('customers', 'users\CustomersController@index');
    Route::get('customers/import', 'users\CustomersController@import');
    Route::post('customers/run-import', 'users\CustomersController@runImport');
});

Comment: One answer from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063520/laravel-slash-after-url-redirects-to-root-folder?lq=1 says that it may be because of a folder in `public` with the same name as url - so, do you have `customers` folder in your `public` folder. I think it's unlikely but good to rule it out. Also do your `customers/import` or `customers/run-import` routes work okay?

Comment: yes i have customers folder in public folder is this an issue? and  run-import and import are ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-name customers folder in public folder and the link is working ok.

Answer (score 4):

Routes cannot have the same name as any folders in your public directory.

Laravel will redirect to the root if you try to access a route when you have a folder with the same name in your public folder.

Credit to user @Lazirro for his answer here: [Laravel slash after url redirects to root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063520/laravel-slash-after-url-redirects-to-root-folder?lq=1)