# How to slashes in the end of url in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

By default in Laravel if there is `/` in the end of url it redirects you to link without `/` in the end. Is it possible to disable this feature and allow `/` in the end of url?

Comment: This may be asked already. . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991230/laravel-how-do-i-make-route-route-return-urls-with-trailing-slashes

Comment: I think you should follow this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063520/laravel-slash-after-url-redirects-to-root-folder)

Answer (score -2):

edit .htaccess file in public folder 
change this : 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1/ [L,R=301]`
to : 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]`